# Maven-postman-plugin: correct configuration for goal, surefire-mail

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm having a whale of a time getting this plugin to mail me failsafe or surefire test results. The send-mail goal works fine (but can't do conditional sending using groovy).  I can send an attachement to my mail recipient.

But, when I run the surefire-mail goal, I send/receive only an email with *no* test results content. I receive an email with the default contents: "build for com.xxxx.yyyy:zzz-abc:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT executed". I have never seen an example of the default test results for this goal. I'm assuming it is something similar to emailable-report.html found in the surefire folder - but not sure.

```xml
<execution>
    <id>send results</id>
    <phase>site</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>surefire-mail</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <subject>[TeamCity] Project A- Test Results</subject>
        <groovyCondition><![CDATA[errors == 0]]></groovyCondition>
        <surefireReportHtml>
            ${project.build.directory}/site/failsafe-report.html
        </surefireReportHtml>
        <testReportsDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports
        </testReportsDirectory>
        <receivers>
            <receiver>first.last@company.com</receiver>
        </receivers>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

I tried with and without the `surefireReportHtml` and `testReportsDirectory` tags. I'm running this: `mvn deploy site`.

Here are my logs:

```
[13:09:39][com.company.project:project-model] [INFO] analyze: surefire reports...
[13:09:39][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] -->F:\work\ff5c2f34c9fedec2\project-model\target\failsafe-reports\TEST-TestSuite‌​.xml 
[13:09:40][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] found TestSuite: errors=0, skipped=0, failures=0, tests=6
[13:09:40][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] test ERRORS: 0 
[13:09:40][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] test SKIPPED: test FAILURES: 0 test TOTAL: 6 ] evaluating groovy condition [errors <= 0 || errors > 0]
```

Comment: here is the mvn log:

Comment: [13:09:39][com.company.project:project-model] [INFO] analyze: surefire reports...
[13:09:39][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] -->F:\work\ff5c2f34c9fedec2\project-model\target\failsafe-reports\TEST-TestSuite.xml
[13:09:40][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] found TestSuite: errors=0, skipped=0, failures=0, tests=6
[13:09:40][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] test ERRORS: 0
[13:09:40][com.company.project:project-model] [DEBUG] test SKIPPED:  test FAILURES: 0
 test TOTAL: 6
] evaluating groovy condition [errors <= 0 || errors > 0]

Answer (score 0):

I used a variation to get this to produce an email of report data. I dropped the surefire-mail goal and used the send-mail goal and just attached the emailable-report.html generated by failsafe.

Hope this helps.

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failonerror>false</failonerror>
                <skip>${test.integration.notif.skip}</skip>
                <mailhost><your mail host subdomain></mailhost>
                <from><your email account id and mail server: eg: id@comcast.net></from>
                <receivers>
                    <receiver><email account id and mail server></receiver>
                </receivers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>send attached failsafe html results notification</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>send-mail</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <subject>[TeamCity] Integration Test Results</subject>
                        <htmlMessage>
                           <![CDATA[
                             <p>
                                 We have new integration test results for:
                                    build: ${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}
                                    rev: ${build.vcs.number}

                                 See attached failsafe report.
                             </p>
                             <br>
                           ]]>
                        </htmlMessage>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/emailable-report.html</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```